Using Django JSONField Like a NoSQL Database for a Quiz Application
I'm developing a Django-based quiz website and would like to use a JSONField in the Quiz model to store questions in a manner similar to NoSQL databases like MongoDB. My plan is to store questions as JSON data directly in the Quiz model (e.g., questions=models.JSONField()). While this simplifies the structure and avoids joins, I'm concerned about how it will perform regarding querying and filtering capabilities. Given this approach, what are the pros and cons of using JSONField for a large dataset in Django? How can I optimize performance and scalability? Any advice or best practices for managing such a structure would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Don't store structured JSON blobs in a relational database.

Djongo is a small package built on top of Django to talk to NoSQL databases.

I don't really see why you want to avoid JOINs. JOINs are typically not a performance issue: as long as you filter the relations properly before the JOINs. The JOINing is often not the performance bottleneck, if filtering is not done properly, it just generates a large amount of useless data.


[I] would like to use a JSONField in the Quiz model to store questions in a manner similar to NoSQL databases like MongoDB.

Storing data in JSON blobs in a relational database is often not a good idea, unless the JSON blobs are "atomic". In other words, if you don't want to filter, aggregate, update, retrieve, etc. parts of the data. But that is not the case here, so it is (very) likely not a good idea.
It would mean that each time you fetch a Quiz, it will fetch the entire JSON blob, which thus results in large responses from the database, making the system less responsive. Keeping data in multiple tables typically results in smaller amounts of data to retrieve, aggregate, filter, etc.

While this simplifies the structure and avoids joins

JOINs are typically not that much of a problem either. If there are proper indexes, and a ForeignKey implies an index, JOINing is done very efficiently. What is more of a problem is not filtering the relations that are JOINed together, resulting again in (useless) large responses from the database.
Using JSON blobs also means you don't have any guarantees about the structure of the JSON blob: one can define a Quiz like {"title": "My fancy quiz", questions: {"question": "What was the shortest light pulse ever produced?", "answer": "Just 43 attoseconds."}}, but one can just dump [0, 1, 1, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 1, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 9, 7, 2, 5, 3] into a record as data. Relational databases are designed to enforce a certain structure on the data, such that non-sense data is not entered.
Djongo [GitHub] is a package that essentially makes a MongoDb binding for Django, although with mixed results. While Django does not per se requires a relational database, it is tailored much towards it, where models explain what such columns look like.
Relational databases indeed nowadays often offer a JSON and/or JSONB field, and even can perform lookups, filter and aggregate. But still these tools often do not work very effectively. Not only in terms of performance, but also in terms of convenience: a lookup in a JSON blob has to be of a certain type so it requires a lot of casting, extra syntax to move through the JSON blob, etc.
Probably it is not a good idea to use it that way, simply because a database like PostgreSQL was not designed (in the beginning) to ever work that way, and although they definitely put a lot of effort into improving it, it will still require a lot of effort for relational databases to be used in a NoSQL-like way.
